# Are the following Moq unit tests composed correctly

Tags: c#, mocking, moq

I have got the following unit tests that utilise Moq and they compile and give me the correct results, however I'm not convinced that I have implemented them correctly, or if I have, then I am misunderstanding what Moq is doing in this situation.

Here are my unit tests:

```
TaskInstance taskInstance_1 = new TaskInstance() { Id = 1, Task = task_1 };
IEnumerable<TaskInstance> _domainTaskInstances = new List<TaskInstance>() 
    { taskInstance_1 };

[TestMethod()]
public void TaskService_CheckForTaskUsage_Success()
{
    _taskInstanceRepository.Setup(x => x.Get(It.IsAny<Expression<Func<
        TaskInstance, bool>>>(), null, "")).Returns(_domainTaskInstances);

    int taskId = 1;
    bool expected = true;
    bool actual;
    actual = GetTarget().CheckForTaskUsage(taskId);
    Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
}

[TestMethod()]
public void TaskService_CheckForTaskUsage_Failure()
{
    _taskInstanceRepository.Setup(x => x.Get(It.IsAny<Expression<Func<
        TaskInstance, bool>>>(), null, "")).Returns(new List<TaskInstance>()
        .AsEnumerable());

    int taskId = 2;
    bool expected = false;
    bool actual;
    actual = GetTarget().CheckForTaskUsage(taskId);
    Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
}
```

The method that I am checking is this:

```
public bool CheckForTaskUsage(int taskId)
{
    return _taskInstanceRepository.Get(x => x.Task.Id == taskId).Any();
}
```

The method that I am mocking is this:

```
IEnumerable<T> Get(Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter = null, Func<IQueryable<T>, 
    IOrderedQueryable<T>> orderBy = null, string includeProperties = "");
```

The `GetTarget()` method creates an instance of the class where the `CheckForTaskUsage()` method resides and `_taskInstanceRepository` is set.

The confusion that I have is down to the `.Returns()` part of the mocking of the `Get()` method in the repository. I'm not sure whether setting the return values as I have done is correct as from my point of view it doesn't seem like it will actually execute the `Get()` method and the expression that is passed into it. However this could be correct as I am not trying to execute the `Get()` method, only return some values for it, but if that was the case, why would I care about the possible parameters that are sent into it?

Thanks

Comment: This probably belongs on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/15330/).

Comment: The `Returns` looks fine to me.  You might want to add a test for if `Get()` returns `null` though. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> from my point of view it doesn't seem like it will actually execute
>   the Get() method and the expression that is passed into it.

That's right - it won't actually get data from the database. Unit tests should test logic not database connectivity.

> why would I care about the possible parameters that are sent into it?

You could test, for example, if certain parameters raise exceptions or return null. It's possible that -1, for example, raises an exception. In which case you'd want tests for that.

Also note other Assert options, such as `Assert.IsTrue`, that might be more suitable.

Comment: Thanks very much for the clarification! As for the `Assert`, I agree, they are just the standard VS-generated ones in the test before I change them to more logical methods!